# Grand total without tax

Tags: cart, tax, shipping-tax

i want and need in cart display Grand Total price without include tax, but tax price should be display in different line.
How i can do this? where i can modify file?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will get you your carts subtotal:

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
```

This will get your your carts grand total:

```
Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal());
```

Comment: ok, good, now how i can get price in cart next:
1. grand total without table rate price?
2. get table rate price? - displayShippingPriceIncludingTax in cart not working
3. get tax value price in cart

Comment: Here's someothing you can do to find variables to call using Magentos getX function system: $subtotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote(); var_dump($subtotal); This will dump all the variables that you can interact with from $subtotal.

Comment: how about tax and shipping?

Comment: @Sergey you could just subtract the grandtotal from the subtotal to get taxed amount

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried this config setting in the admin panel?

System > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings

[image: System > Configuration > Tax > Shopping Cart Display Settings]

Comment: You are welcome @PriyaPonnusamy!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured it out. Appertently it's a core bug in Magento 1.9.2.4.

Go to: app/code/core/Mage/Tax/etc/config.xml

Change line: 165

From:

```
<after>freeshipping</after>
```

To:

```
<after>subtotal,nominal,shipping,freeshipping</after>
```

Read about the fix here:

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/84

Comment: This actually fixed a similar bug on V 1.7.0.2 somehow.  Perhaps was part of a security patch

Answer (score 1):

This is magento bug.

Add this line of code in `app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php` at **1532** line no.

```
if ($this->_config->displayCartTaxWithGrandTotal($store)) {
            $grandTotal = $address->getSubtotal() + $address->getShippingAmount() + $taxAmount - $address->getShippingTaxAmount();
            $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
}
```